# How to load favicon in django server from react build folder? manifest.json not found error

Tags: python, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I have developed a website using react as frontend and Django as backend, I have completed the project and made npm run build and I have added the index.html into the Django templates DIR and static files which are inside the build folder

But manifest.json, favicon.ico   which is inside the public and build folder are not visible in Django page which localhost:8000, favicon is visible in React page which is in localhost:3000

Project Structure:

```
Project
  |__backend
    |__settings.py
    |__urls.py
  |__base --app
    |__views.py
    |__models.py
  |__build -- reactjs npm run build
    |__assets - folder which has images
    |__static -- css and scss folder
    |__manifest.json
    |__favicon.ico
    |__index.html
  |__public
  |__src
  |__static -- django static folder
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static',
    BASE_DIR / 'build/static',
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/assets'),
]

MEDIA_ROOT  = 'static/images'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Errors in terminal:

```
Not Found: /manifest.json
[04/Sep/2021 14:03:50] "GET /manifest.json HTTP/1.1" 404 2788
```

Comment: Did your issue solved, I'm also facing the same issue

Comment: No, I couldn't solve the issue , now i am using nodejs as backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario, Django doesn't need `manifest.json` to load the `favicon` if you just want to load the `favicon`, You can add your favicon in the media upload directory. In your case, it's `images`.

After that, the URL to Load favicon should be like that

```
http://localhost:8000/static/images/favicon.ico
```

Then you just have to replace the URL from Public/index.html

from

```
<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
```

To

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://localhost:8000/static/images/favicon.ico" />
```

That's it. Now reload the Page and your favicon will be available as expected.

> If you want to load `manifest.json` correctly then you can use the same
> approach configuring the URL like previously done with favicon.

Comment: Thank you @FaisalNazik its working in localhost, but its not working in live , i guess i should mention the deployed host name in this url ````http://localhost:8000/static/images/favicon.ico``` instead of localhost , is there any way to do that dynamically

Comment: Yes it did, thank you for your help

Comment: @FaisalNazik will this work with the images that is present in the build folder, will you have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71998700/django-not-rendering-the-images-present-in-the-images-folder-inside-the-build please

Comment: Yes, you can manually place the Constructed URLs as I used for the favicon from Django static folder. directly to build/index.js e.g:
`http://localhost:8000/static/images/imagefile.png`