# Django not rendering the images present in the 'images' folder inside the build folder after merging the react app

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-settings

I have a React App with a Django rest framework backend. I ran the build command and merged the react app. The react app had an images folder inside the public folder that had some logos and photos that I used during the frontend development. Now after running the build and rendering the site from Django it is unable to render the images. The folder **images** is present inside the build folder that react gives. Below are my configurations and settings.

**project structure**

```
┣ build
 ┃ ┣ images
 ┃ ┃ ┣ footer-logo.svg
 ┃ ┃ ┣ hero_illustration_student_register.svg
 ┃ ┃ ┣ logo_favicon.svg
 ┃ ┃ ┣ logo_name_header.svg
 ┃ ┃ ┣ only-logo.svg
 ┃ ┃ ┣ quote-left-solid.svg
 ┃ ┃ ┣ quote-right-solid.svg
 ┃ ┃ ┣ service_student_teacher.svg
 ┃ ┃ ┣ student.svg
 ┃ ┃ ┗ Teacher.svg
 ┃ ┣ static
 ┃ ┃ ┣ css
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ main.701fe633.css
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ main.701fe633.css.map
 ┃ ┃ ┗ js
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ main.492ffbea.js
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ main.492ffbea.js.LICENSE.txt
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ main.492ffbea.js.map
 ┃ ┣ asset-manifest.json
 ┃ ┣ index.html
 ┃ ┣ manifest.json
 ┃ ┗ robots.txt
 ┣ schoolies
 ┃ ┣ __pycache__
 ┃ ┃ ┣ settings.cpython-39.pyc
 ┃ ┃ ┣ urls.cpython-39.pyc
 ┃ ┃ ┣ wsgi.cpython-39.pyc
 ┃ ┃ ┗ __init__.cpython-39.pyc
 ┃ ┣ asgi.py
 ┃ ┣ settings.py
 ┃ ┣ urls.py
 ┃ ┣ wsgi.py
 ┃ ┗ __init__.py
```

**template settings**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build'),
            ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

**static and media files settings**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'build/static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('account/', include("account.urls")),
    path('teacher/', include("teacher.urls")),
    path('search/', include("search.urls")),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)


# This is will cath the routes in the frontend and 404 errors
urlpatterns += [re_path(r'^.*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))]
```

**cmd lines after the page loads**

```
[25/Apr/2022 17:00:27] "GET /static/css/main.701fe633.css.map HTTP/1.1" 200 38691
[25/Apr/2022 17:00:27] "GET /static/js/main.82ff440d.js.map HTTP/1.1" 200 2170125
[25/Apr/2022 17:00:27] "GET /images/hero_illustration_student_register.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 833
[25/Apr/2022 17:00:27] "GET /images/logo_name_header.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 833
[25/Apr/2022 17:00:27] "GET /images/footer-logo.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 833
[25/Apr/2022 17:00:27] "GET /manifest.json HTTP/1.1" 200 833
[25/Apr/2022 17:00:27] "GET /logo_favicon.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 833
```

Please suggest to me what should I do

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem. I am answering this question if in future somebody faces the same problem.

What I did is in the public folder in the react end I made a folder called the **static** and inside that I put the **images** folder. Then I ran the npm run build command which put the **images** folder in the static folder that react gives after build. And also changed the the image source inside the react end to the below source

```
<img src="/static/images/picture.jpg" />
```

And this did the job